# Solvability condition for the Duffing equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-analysis

I'm trying to understand the derivation of the [solvability condition for the Duffing equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple-scale_analysis#Solution).

Using the method of multiple scales we can write the first order problem for the Duffing equation as:

$$\partial^2_t Y_1 + Y_1 = - Y_0^3 -2 \partial_{t,t_1} Y_0$$

Where $t_1 = \varepsilon t$ and $Y_0(t,t_1)=A(t_1)e^{it} + C.C.$ (C.C. stands for complex conjugate). To get the solvability equation from here we express the previous equation as (we look for solutions in $L^2$):

$$ \mathcal{L}(Y_1) = b$$

And then if we consider $u \in$ Ker$(\mathcal{L}^\dagger)$ we would have:

$$<u|b>=<u|\mathcal{L}(Y_1)>=<\mathcal{L}^\dagger(u)|Y_1>=0$$

I have found that $\mathcal{L}=\mathcal{L}^\dagger$ so $u=Ce^{it}+De^{-it}$. Taking now the scalar product is clear that to get 0 we need to impose the condition

$$-3A^2A^* -2i \frac{dA}{dt_1} = 0$$

but there is also another couple of terms of the form $-A^3 (De^{2it}+Ce^{4it})$. Why are these terms not relevant? I don't see that they go to 0 when you integrate. I know that they're bounded, but I don't know now how to see that they are exactly 0.

Why don't we consider these terms for the solvability condition?